# Bootstrap modal not opening when button pressed

Tags: javascript, reactjs, bootstrap-modal, bootstrap-5, vite

Im trying to make a bootstrap modal show when I press a button, heres the code:
(btw Im using React and Vitejs as the builder with this)

```
function Test() {

    return(
        <>
        <div className="container">
        <button className="btn" data-bs-toggle="modal" data-bs-target="#modaltest">Press</button>
            <div id="modaltest" className="modal">
                <div className="modal-dialog">
                    <div className="modal-content">
                        Content
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
        </>
    );
}

export default Test;
```

Heres my package.json just in case. I checked and Im using bootstrap ver 5 so it shouldnt be the -bs- thing in the class name.

```
{
  "name": "portfolio",
  "private": true,
  "version": "0.0.0",
  "type": "module",
  "scripts": {
    "dev": "vite",
    "build": "vite build",
    "lint": "eslint . --ext js,jsx --report-unused-disable-directives --max-warnings 0",
    "preview": "vite preview"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "react": "^18.2.0",
    "react-dom": "^18.2.0"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@types/react": "^18.2.15",
    "@types/react-dom": "^18.2.7",
    "@vitejs/plugin-react": "^4.0.3",
    "bootstrap": "^5.3.2",
    "eslint": "^8.45.0",
    "eslint-plugin-react": "^7.32.2",
    "eslint-plugin-react-hooks": "^4.6.0",
    "eslint-plugin-react-refresh": "^0.4.3",
    "sass": "^1.68.0",
    "vite": "^4.4.5"
  }
}
```

I press the button, but nothing happens.
Im testing in a vite dev server
Any ideas?

Thanks!

Comment: According to the docs, regular Bootstrap JavaScript is not compatible with React.  You might want to try the React Bootstrap package.

Comment: @rby Oh, I had no idea. Will check it.
Thxs!

Comment: @rby It works with react-bootstrap <3

Comment: Did [you](https://stackoverflow.com/users/14043919/dmo) import the bootstrap css file?

Comment: @NikhilDevadiga
Yes, before trying react-bootstrap which ended up working for me I had been using bootstrap without issues. I had "import 'bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.css';" imported in main.jsx.